# how tensorflow detemines which variable to compute grandients and update it

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I recently work on `tensorflow` and have some doubt about auto grad in `tensorflow`. Say we have a lost function `loss = sigmod (theta * x)`, where `x` is a placeholder and represent out input features and `theta` is the parameter. when we call `sess.run`, how to determine `x` or `theta` to compute gradient and update to it.
Does tf compute gradients of loss w.r.t both `x` and `theta` `gradients` and update both?

Answer (score 1):

> how to determine `x` or `theta` to compute gradient and update to it?

Actually, it's pretty straightforward. A [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) constructor has an argument `trainable`. When it is set to true (which is a default, by the way) the variable is added to the graph collection [`GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables). So at any moment you can invoke [`tf.trainable_variables()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/trainable_variables) to see the variables that are going to be updated through backprop.

When you specify this kind of dependency: `loss = sigmod (theta * x)`, a `tf.Variable` is created under the hood and of course it's trainable.

A [`tf.placeholder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder) only adds a node to the graph. The name means that the node just a placeholder for a tensor that will always be fed and it's not added to the trainable collectioin.

Answer (score 0):

When you define theta in your code, you will use tf.Variable(....),while if you define x, you use tf.placeholder.
I guess that's how tensorflow determines to do gradient descent on x or theta.
It shall always compute gradients on a Variable instead of a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform autograd manually with [tf.gradients(...)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/gradients). This function accepts arbitrary tensors (including placeholders, op outputs, and variables) for `xs` and `ys` and creates operation for the partial derivates of `ys` w.r.t. `xs` as long as the gradients can be computed along the graph between the tensors.

In most cases, you will use a [tf.train.Optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer#class_optimizer) to compute the gradients and variable update operations for your model. By default, its method `compute_gradients(...)` will generate the update operations for all variables marked as `trainable` (see [tf.get_variable(...)](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable)). You can also manually specify the variables you want to update with the `var_list` arugment of `compute_gradients(...)`. In any case, only the necessary gradient operations will be generated and executed.